# VLC for Android: No connection to local network

Tags: linux, vlc, cifs

All of a sudden, my VLC for Android app just up and stopped showing the local LAN network shares which are Samba running on a Xubuntu 20.04 host.  I have no clue to what caused this. I have verified that the share is indeed shared via this on that Linux host that has the samba service activated:

```
$ smbclient -L wilddog
Enter WORKGROUP\XXXX's password: 

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    samba_share     Disk      Shared Folder
    print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (XXXXX server (Samba, Ubuntu))
    testprinter     Printer   
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available
$
```

From the VLC For Android app, all I see now is this:

[image]

EDIT: I have rebooted both the phone, and the Linux server, to no avail.  I've also restarted the samba server on the Linux server, also to no avail.

What do I need to do to diagnose this?

Comment: Have you checked the Samba log files on the server?

Comment: Ah. Yes. That.  I checked it, and no such connection from the IP address of my phone. So that leads me back to figuring out why the phone itself is not able to see that local network. Thank you very much. I'll self-answer this question with the details.

Answer (score 1):

[Robert's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246835/vlc-for-android-no-connection-to-local-network#comment330747_246835) clued me into the fact that  the phone itself had somehow gotten into a mode whereby the main WiFI icon that is displayed on the phone did **not** reflect the connection status as it should have IMO. No indication about which WiFI it was connected to was available, *until which time that* I long-pressed onto that icon, and saw that it listed WiFI networks, but was **not** connected. Once I connected to my WiFI network, I was able to then see the SMB shares in the VLC app. See annotated screenshot below:

[image]